# Keep dropdown menu open when navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I get some issue while hovering the dropdown menu, it slideup when I move the cursor out from the mouseenter ID to go under the sub menu to navigate. 
I tore my hair all the day to fix this issue, I tried many example which I found on the net but I did not found a solution.
Any help would be appreciated

```
 var menu = $('.menu')
 menu.hide();
 $("#mainbutton").mouseenter(function(){
   $(".menu").stop().slideDown("fast");
 });
 $("#mainbutton").mouseleave(function(){
   $(".menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qcexeu9d/)

Comment: Why don't you just slide down on click and then slide up when the user clicks elsewhere?

Comment: Usually child links are within the parent. I would change the HTML.

Comment: CSS-Tricks has a quite comprehensive article about how to prevent  hover-controlled menus from closing too quick: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/

Answer (score 3):

Make it slideup when you leave the whole `nav`:

```
 $("#nav").mouseleave(function(){
   $(".menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
 });
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qcexeu9d/2/)

Comment: We don't know that `.menu` is within `#nav`

Comment: @Popnoodles It is, look at the fiddle given. It's basically the wrapper of the entire menu.

Comment: Duh, I didn't see the fiddle.

Comment: Fortunately you posted this sensible answer before I came back with [my ugly hack](http://jsfiddle.net/qcexeu9d/5/)!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("#dropdown_container").mouseleave(function(){
       $(".menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
     });
```

Here's a working example/code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     var menu = $('.menu')
     menu.hide();
     $("#mainbutton").mouseenter(function(){
       $(".menu").stop().slideDown("fast");
     });
     $("#dropdown_container").mouseleave(function(){
       $(".menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
     });

    // Slide Tabs
 // Insert Slider
 $('.nav_slide_title').append('<div id="slider"></div>');
 // Initially Reset
 var left = $('.nav_slide_title > li a').parent().position().left;
 var width = $('.nav_slide_title > li a').width();
 
 $('#slider').css({'left' : left, 'width' : width});

 // Sliding
 $('a.sub_title').hover(function(){
    
     var left = $(this).parent().position().left;
     var width = $(this).width();
     
     $('#slider').stop().animate({
         'left' : left,
         'width' : width, duration:400
     });
 });
    
      // Tabs Content
    $(".nav_slide_title li").hover(function() {
        $(".tab-content").removeClass('tab-show');
        $(".tab-titles li").removeClass('active');                  
        $(this).addClass("active");                 
        var selected_tab = $(this).find(".sub_title").attr("name");
        $(selected_tab).addClass("tab-show");
    });
    
}); // End
```

```css
span:focus,a:focus { outline: 0; border: none }
.nav_clear::before, .nav_clear::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both
}
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible
}
ul,li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none
}
#nav a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CFCFCF
}
/* First Title */
#nav #nav_wrapper > li {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 1.85em;
    padding: 0% 6.5% 0% 0%
}
#nav #nav_wrapper > li.first { padding-left: 7.5% }
#nav #nav_wrapper > li > a {
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding: 0.3em 1.6em;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color:#000
}
/* End First Title */
#dropdown_container {
    background:#222;
    height: 300px;
    overflow:visible
}
#dropdown_container .nav_slide_title {
    position: relative;
    height: 48px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #222;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #4C4C4C;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden
}
#dropdown_container .nav_slide_title > li {
    float: left;
    width: 16.66%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align:  center   
}
#dropdown_container .nav_slide_title .sub_title {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    border: medium none;
    color: #D8D8D8;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    z-index: 1
}
#dropdown_container .tab-content { display: none }
#dropdown_container .tab-show { 
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff
}
#dropdown_container #slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 16.66% !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
    z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
 <nav id="nav">
  <ul id="nav_wrapper" class="nav_clear">
   <li class="first">
    <a id="mainbutton" href="#">Menu1</a>
   </li>
   <li class="second">
    <a id="" href="#">Menu2</a>
   </li>
   <!-- Drop down Joaillerie -->
   <div id="dropdown_container" class="menu nav_clear">
    <ul class="nav_slide_title">
     <li><a class="sub_title" href="#" name="#tab1" >tabs1</a></li>     
     <li><a class="sub_title" href="#" name="#tab2" >tabs2</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub_title" href="#" name="#tab3" >tabs3</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub_title" href="#" name="#tab4" >tabs4</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub_title" href="#" name="#tab5" >tabs5</a></li>
     <li><a class="sub_title" href="#" name="#tab6" >tabs6</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content tab-show">
     <div class="taglist">Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content nav_clear">
     <div>Content 2</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content nav_clear">
     <div>Content 3</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content nav_clear">
     <div>Content 4</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab-content nav_clear">
     <div>Content 5</div> 
    </div>
    <div id="tab6" class="tab-content nav_clear">
     <div>Content 6</div> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </nav> 
</div> <!-- Navbar -->
```